# Azure function - send all requests to the same function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I'm trying to set up Azure function so that all requests are sent to the same function.  The `proxies.json` file is extremely simple:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "Root URI to Redirector Trigger Function": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{*path}",
        "methods": [
          "GET",
          "POST"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "http://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/myfunc"
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good, but when a request is sent, the proxied requests ends up being processed by the proxy again - ending in an infinite loop.

How can I specify in my proxies to proxy all requests accept those to `/myfunc` resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue, although it's not very elegant.  My `proxies.json` now looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "Root URI to Redirector Trigger Function": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{path}",
        "methods": [
          "GET",
          "POST"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "http://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/"
    }
  }
}
```

I also edited my `function.json` to have `"route": "/".  Now all calls to anything other than root are proxied to my function. Calls to route end up going to the function directly (and need to be handled separately).

Answer (score 1):

You configuration forces the redirection to apply to everything on the domain.  When redirection occurs, `/myfunc` also gets re-directed.

You can:
 1. Change the route of your proxies to something different, f.e. `/api/{*path}'.
 2. Move your function to a different domain.